# app crashing if I am doing CGImageRelease(sourceImageRef),objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgimageref

My first post is at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170699/can-not-get-clue-from-zombie-about-a-crash#comment21367412_15170699) to look for the reason why my app is crashing. After almost 3 hours to detect and now I can find out where the leak is.

First of all, what I am doing is after downloading an image using AFNetworking, I will be setting the size of uiimageview regarding to the size of downloaded image.

```
[self.headerView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fundraiserInfo.imageUrl]]
                       placeholderImage:nil
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                    // Use following to set the size of image according to retina or non retina
                                    CGImageRef sourceImageRef   =   [image CGImage];
                                    UIImage *newImage           =   [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImageRef scale:[image scale]                                                                                           orientation:[image imageOrientation]];
                                    CGImageRelease(sourceImageRef); // <------ this is I am getting crash
                                    weakObj.image  = newImage;                                                                                                    
                                 }
                                 failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                        ;
                                 }
 ];
```

I am getting warning like below

```
Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

How I can detect the leak :

Putting that line and run the app, the app is crashing after several tries. By detecting after 2 hours, I can reproduce the error. If I remove that line and follow exactly what I do to reproduce the error, the app is running properly and no crashing at all.

Any thought why that line is the reason to crash my app

Comment: Why you are CGImageRelease(sourceImageRef); releasing this unless you have not created or retain it?

Comment: @Bhargavi:did I create it by using `[image CGImage]`, didn't I ? That is why I release it after `newImage` is created. I may be wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only referencing sourceImageRef using `CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [image CGImage];` . More over you are not creating, retaining it, so it is not your responsibility to release it.

I would like you to look at post [Releasing CGImageRef](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51569-releasing-cgimageref.html).

Also look at [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567465/cgimageref-memory-leak) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574785/cgimagerelease-not-a-type-release-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance)